# How can we strengthen belief in the coming of Moshiach and the end of our exile?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, messiah

We believe that Moshiach will come and our exile will end soon.

How can we strengthen this belief?

Answers supported by sources are preferred.

Comment: How do you strengthen belief in anything?

Comment: I disagree with the premise that we believe he will come soon. We believe he will come, and we hope it will be soon.

Comment: This a very good study and this is si different than I was taught. The whole study onMoshiach is so hard to teach right. The big thing is to teach it right. He is not G-d like Christian teach he is very special but he is a man.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, **R' Shalom Arush** states in his book **The Garden of Emuna** that If you say something over and over again, you will increase your belief (emuna) in it. Therefore, anyone who says the section from [Ani Maamin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ani_Ma%27amin) that deals with the [Moshiach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshiach) will increase his belief in his coming over time. Unfortunately I do not remember which page he says this on.

Answer (score 2):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe says in a sicha (Tazria-Metzora; Sefer HaSichos 5751) that the direct way to bring Moshiach is to learn about Moshiach and Geula. How can you believe in something that you have no clue about? Moshiach is not just a idea or a philosophy, Moshiach is a man of flesh and blood. Geulah is not just an idea either, it is an physical reality that we will physically experience. The Lubavitcher Rebbe pushed the Kehot (official Lubavitcher Publishing Company) to compile and print a set of seforim called "Yalkut Inyanei Geulah U'Moshiach for this very reason. The seforim source everything from Tanach, Talmud, Midrash, Rishionim, all the way up to current day Jewish leaders, Chassidic, Sephardi, and even Litvish. Just like you cant appreciate nuclear physics or the process of brain surgery, how can you "believe", "appreciate", and "yearn" for Moshiach and Geulah if you have not the slightest clue what either mean?

Comment: I've heard that the Rambam says that there is no point of learning about what will happen around Mashiach because it "doesn't make one love Hashem or fear Hashem."

Comment: @HachamGabriel I would like to see your source for this seeing as in his Mishneh Torah in Hilchos Melachim he does just that.

Comment: @mochinrechavim His Mishne Torah spends very little time on specifics. I too would like to see this quote inside.

Comment: @doubleAA see yad ch. 12 end of halacha 2

Comment: Thanks @ShmuelBrin  ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדבר ההגדות ולא יאריך במדרשות האמורים בענינים אלו וכיוצא בהן ולא ישימם עיקר שאין מביאין לא לידי יראה ולא לידי אהבה וכן לא יחשב הקצין אמרו חכמים תפח רוחם של מחשבי הקצים אלא יחכה ויאמין בכלל הדבר כמו שבארנו:

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Thanks! I knew it sounded familiar.

Comment: That doesnt mean that we dont know what will happen. That means that we can not claim to know the timeline of Moshiach since in the very same chapter he discuss multiple events that will happen when Moshiach comes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it sometimes helps to listen or read about stories of great rabbis who possessed this true emunah. When you hear about how they would actually make active decisions based on their faith of the redemption, it could stir up such feelings in you. (At least from my personal experience.) For example, I heard of a great rabbi (perhaps Rabbi Moshe teitelbaum - the great great grandfather of the last Samar rebbe?) who actually hired and paid somebody to be his shomer - guard - who would wake him up from his sleep immediately if he would hear the blasts of the shofar that herald the coming of the messiah

Answer (score 0):

Read:

[*The Future: Guide to Messiah*](http://www.feldheim.com/the-future-guide-to-messiah.html)
A GUIDE TO THE JEWISH MESSIAH, ISRAEL, AND THE END OF DAYS by Rabbi Lawrence Hajioff

In this fascinating work, Rabbi Lawrence Hajioff delves into these questions using Jewish sources that span thousands of years exploring such topics as:

- The Four Exiles of Jewish history
- The King Mashiach and his mission
- Israel and Jerusalem at the End of Days
- The War of Gog and Magog
- The purpose of the World to Come
- Resurrection of the Dead

The Chofetz Chayim says, *“If we were truly yearning for the final Redemption and waiting each day for its arrival, then we would be preparing ourselves by learning the relevant halachos, for there are many halachos to be learned and they cannot all be covered in a short time… For if it would be revealed that in a short time the final Redemption would arrive, then certainly millions of Jews would quickly learn the halachos to the Beis HaMikdosh, since at that time all of these halachos will be applicable, not only for kohanim but for all Jews, for instance, the halachos regarding eating karbonos and visiting the Mikdash… Therefore, if we are truly waiting and yearning for the final Redemption… we too should arouse ourselves and learn these halachos with all our strength.”*

Is there any sefer that exists nowadays which has relevant halachos regarding the Beis HaMikdosh?

Yes! It’s called [*Days Are Coming*](https://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/Days-Are-Coming-12p870.htm) by Rabbi Moshe Silberstein.

By studying this sefer, one is imbuing himself with faith that Hashem will redeem us. The Chofeitz Chayim had a special morning coat that he planned to wear to greet Moshiach and from time to time he put it on and sit in anticipation. Therefore, a person should designate some type of article of clothing – i.e. suit, shirt, hat, belt or shoes etc., that he/ she has designated to wear when Moshiach reveals himself. As the Sefer HaChinuch says, “A person is fashioned by his deeds.” Saying the 12th Principle of the Ani Ma’amins every day or learning Seider Kodshim isn’t enough [excerpted from [*Rubashkin, the Redemption and Yearning for Moshiach*](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/70397), question #3].